# getting error when trying to use custom route in anchor tag helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've created a route with template "**/documentation/{category?}/{feature?}**" and named it *docu*, but I get an error when I try to use it in the anchor tag helper.

Link:

```html
<a asp-route="docu" 
   asp-route-category="layout" 
   asp-route-feature="colors" 
   asp-page-handler="Feature" class="link">Color</a>
```

Error:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot determine the 'href' attribute for
> . The following attributes are mutually exclusive: asp-route
> asp-controller, asp-action asp-page, asp-page-handler

It works if I use **@Url.RouteUrl()** in the cshtml file, but I don't know if I get access to it in a tag helper.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

Like the exception tells you, the main problem here is that you're simultaneously using both

1. `asp-page-handler` and
2. `asp-route`.

The first is for generating a URL to a Razor Page, while the latter is for generating a URL to a named route. The two are mutually exclusive, so you simply need to pick one and remove the other.

Answer (score 1):

Color

You are missing the last part of the asp-rout-color="docu"

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with usin the IUrlHelper in a custom tag helper instead of using the anchor helper.

```
services.AddScoped<IUrlHelper>(x =>
{
    var actionContext = x.GetRequiredService<IActionContextAccessor>().ActionContext;
    var factory = x.GetRequiredService<IUrlHelperFactory>();

    return factory.GetUrlHelper(actionContext);
});
```